# La única manera de

Tags: traducción

Are there other alternatives to say *The only way to learn spanish is by speaking with native speakers*?

> La única manera de aprender castellano es hablar con hispanohablantes.

Comment: @AlfredoOsorio Querrás decir sustituir "es hablar" por "es hablando"

Comment: @SysDragon cierto :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"La única forma de aprender español, es hablar con españoles"

Also "hablando" is much common:

"La única forma de aprender Español, es hablando con españoles"

But not enough: "españoles" means people born in Spain.

"La única forma de aprender español es hablando con hispanos"

Closer, if you say "Hispano" you are referring intrinsically to "native speakers". But i believe LatinAmericans does not tends to use "Hispanos".

"La mejor forma de aprender español, es hablando con alguien que hable español"

But not everyone who speak Spanish is a "Native Speaker".

"La mejor forma de aprender español, es con alguien cuya lengua materna sea el español"

Better, but "lengua materna" could be very formal.

"La mejor forma de aprender español, es con alguien que hable español de nacimiento"

Even better, this means that the speaker speak Spanish since born, so this means he/she is a Native Speaker.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way I would translate it, the most common way probably. But you could also say:

> Para aprender castellano *no hay más remedio* que hablar con
>   hispanohablantes.

Comment: That sounds good. However sometimes the English idiom _"The only way to..."_ is used to mean _"The best way to..."_, for instance _"Business class is the only way to travel"_ the OP doesn't say but his sentence could be understood this way and translated as "Para aprender castellano _lo mejor_ es hablar con hispanohablantes".

Comment: Yeah, there is always more than one way to do things, so "the only way" is "the best way" hehe. Tienes razón, "lo mejor es" es la mejor traducción :P

Comment: _Es la única manera_ de traducirlo :)

Comment: Using 'no hay mas remedio' in that context is not right... You use that when you have a pessimistic situation. For example, when a Doctor has to amputate a patient's leg because there is no other thing left to do.

Comment: Well, "la única manera" is not very optimistic either hehe. But yeah, we use "no hay más remedio" when we don't like the solution.